# SVN Tag Incorrectly Includes Tags/Branches Folders

Tags: svn, version-control

I've not seen SVN do this before and it's throwing me off a bit.  I'm trying to create a tag of the trunk basically.

I have a working copy on disk like:

```
root\branches
root\tags
root\trunk
```

I right click on the trunk folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Branch/Tag...

In the dialog the from is as expected:

```
http://machinename:8080/svn/MyRepo/trunk
```

And the to is:

```
/tags/0.6.631.838
```

I've got the specific revision selected and 838 speficied in the version box.  When I create this tag I get the following structure:

```
/tags/0.6.631.838/branches
/tags/0.6.631.838/tags
/tags/0.6.631.838/trunk
```

I swear this is wrong, the tag should just contain the contents of the trunk shouldn't it?  I'm sure this is how I've seen it work in the past.

What do I need to do to just tag the trunk contents?

Comment: This is not an issue with subversion itself. If at all it would be an issue with TurtoiseSVN, which is the client, a 3rdparty client. But anyways, more likely this is simply a case of accidential wrong usage. Most likely you simply selected the wrong folder to run the action on, one level to far up.

Comment: Does it happen all the time or only once? The "Copy (Branch / Tag)" dialogue offers a preview of all relevant info. Does it look correct?

Comment: It happens all the time, so confusing.  I just did a `copy to` and it worked as expected ...

Comment: Oh BTW `Copy To` doesn't give a preview.

Comment: Weird... Mine does; always have :-?

Comment: Hmm ... this is weird.  I've lost count of the number of tags I've made over the years and I've never seen it do this before.